# Defining class constants in facades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a couple of libraries defined for my Laravel application which expose constants.

For example, I have a class for calculating holidays and work days, used for counting the number of working days for some reports.

My class definition looks like this:

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Libraries;

/**
 * The Holiday Calculation Helper Library
 *
 * A helper class to calculate holidays and working days.
 */
class Holidays {

    /**
     * The defined EBS holidays: New Years Day
     */
    const NEW_YEARS_DAY          = "new years day";
    /**
     * The defined EBS holidays: Independence Day
     */
    const INDEPENDENCE_DAY       = "independence day";
    /**
     * The defined EBS holidays: Christmas Day
     */
    const CHRISTMAS_DAY          = "christmas day";

    ...
```

These are used by (for example) a `date` method which takes the holiday constant value and a year and returns the date of that holiday in that year. I have a facade and a service provider set up so this library can be used in **The Laravel Way™**.Everything works perfectly, I have unit tests for everything, and I'm happy with the code.

The question I have is about how to refer to these constants. If I'm using the facade and calling the library from other parts of my code, it looks like this:

```
$xmas = \Holidays::date(\MyApp\Libraries\Holidays::CHRISTMAS_DAY, "2014");
```

It works, but I'd prefer to use the facade to do it, like this:

```
$xmas = \Holidays::date(\Holidays::CHRISTMAS_DAY, "2014");
```

One solution I thought of is to define the constants in the facade. This works, but then I'm separating the constant values from the library - for obvious reasons, I'd prefer to keep the values with the code that they're associated with.

Then, I hit on another solution: define the constants as above, then reference them in the facade like so:

```
<?php namespace MyApp\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Holidays extends Facade {

    /**
     * The defined EBS holidays: New Years Day
     */
    const NEW_YEARS_DAY          = \MyApp\Libraries\Holidays::NEW_YEARS_DAY;
    /**
     * The defined EBS holidays: Independence Day
     */
    const INDEPENDENCE_DAY       = \MyApp\Libraries\Holidays::INDEPENDENCE_DAY;
    /**
     * The defined EBS holidays: Christmas Day
     */
    const CHRISTMAS_DAY          = \MyApp\Libraries\Holidays::CHRISTMAS_DAY;

    ...
```

Now I can refer to the constants through the facade instead of the fully-qualified library class, and I only have to define a value for the constant once (although I do need to add any new constants to both the library and the facade). This works, and it gets me what I want, but it feels a little like a violation of the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

So here's the question. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: DRY or not, your method works and has helped me today. I suggest post your own solution as an answer even if you don't think it is elegant. So far it is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `use` to alias your `\MyApp\Libraries\Holidays` class, but unfortunately, using `Holidays` will throw a fatal error, so I'd suggest aliasing it as `Holiday` which may also save you some confusion in the future.

Add before you declare your class declaration and after you declare your namespace...

```
use \MyApp\Libraries\Holidays as Holiday;
```

Use inside your class like so....

```
$xmas = \Holidays::date(Holiday::CHRISTMAS_DAY, "2014");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think a better choice might be to alias it with a name that's not so close to the original class - `Holiday` vs. `Holidays` is probably going to mess me up :-) Maybe `Holidays` and `HolidayList`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I go about loading constants, is to add the file to "classmap" directive in composer.json

For e.g. (same as i use)
"**classmap**": [
            "database",
            "app/RolfK/Constants.php"
        ],

Class is defined in the file.